# Find exact match of text in excel array (from another sheet) and display a specific cell value from the same row

Tags: vba, excel

I am comparing two separate spreadsheets.  I need to write a formula that will find the exact text in the other sheet (if it exists), and will then display a value in the corresponding row only 5 cells over.

I have tried various iterations of Index Match to no avail.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  The sheets are formatted roughly the same way.

Let me know if I am not being clear enough.

I used this formula, but it is displaying data regardless of whether or not the cell data matches data in the other sheet's row.

=IF(ISERROR(INDEX(product_performance!$A$2:$E$850,SMALL(IF(product_performance!$A$2:$A$345050=$A$13,ROW(product_performance!$A$2:$A$3450)),ROW(1:1)),8)),"",INDEX(product_performance!$A$2:$H$3450,SMALL(IF(product_performance!$A$2:$A$3450=$A$13,ROW(product_performance!$A$2:$A$3450)),ROW(1:1)),8))

Answer (score 1):

You cannot ask for the 8<sup>th</sup> column within $A$2:$E$850 because that only references 5 columns. The formula you are using seems to be for returning a *first, second, third, etc.* matching value but your narrative gives no mention of multiple returns. For single returns, a [VLOOKUP function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/vlookup-function-adceda66-30de-4f26-923b-7257939faa65) or [INDEX](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/index-function-0ee99cef-a811-4762-8cfb-a222dd31368a)/[MATCH](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/match-function-0600e189-9f3c-4e4f-98c1-943a0eb427ca) function pair would be best.

```
'vlookup
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP($A13, product_performance!$A$2:$H$3450, 8, FALSE), "")
'index/match
=IFERROR(INDEX(product_performance!$A$2:$H$3450, MATCH($A13, product_performance!$A$2:$A$3450, 0), 8), "")
=IFERROR(INDEX(product_performance!$H$2:$H$3450, MATCH($A13, product_performance!$A$2:$A$3450, 0)), "")
```

For multiple returns, throw out the [SMALL function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SMALL-function-4050a82e-659a-4ef6-a970-c963a6f69c29) in favor of the newer [AGGREGATE¹ function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AGGREGATE-function-43B9278E-6AA7-4F17-92B6-E19993FA26DF). As a standard (non-array) formula,

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(product_performance!$H:$H, AGGREGATE(15, 6, ROW($1:$3450)/(product_performance!$A$1:$A$3450=$A$13), ROW(1:1))), "")
```

Fill down for subsequent returns.

The [IFERROR function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/IFERROR-function-F59BACDC-78BD-4924-91DF-A869D0B08CD5) has been around sinbce xl2007 and drastically reduces the formula needed for error control of `IF(ISERROR(...`.

Comment: I was looking at the sheets incorrectly.  A simple V LOOKUP was all I needed...  thanks for chiming in though.